# IllegalArgumentException when using GSON's fromJson()

Tags: java, json, javafx, gson

I have this exception when trying to parse a JSON file with GSON:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.sun.javafx.jmx.HighlightRegion declares multiple JSON fields named hash
```

I have tested a little to what causes this, and I found that it only occurs when I create a Object that has an Event object as a member. In this case, I am trying to create a `List` of Quest objects that eventually have Event objects.

```
package Quests;

import Events.EventSequence;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Quest {

    public static void parseQuest() {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        FileReader questGSON;
        try {
            questGSON = new FileReader(QUEST_FILE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        JsonObject questJSON = gson.fromJson(questGSON, JsonObject.class);

        questList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> element : questJSON.entrySet()) {
            questList.add(gson.fromJson(element.getValue(), Quest.class));
        }
    }

}
```

I am using javafx in that class in the following way:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public abstract class Event implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    // members of this class
    private String title, text;
    private Button[] buttonSet;
    protected Entity other;
    protected Event nextEvent;

    public abstract Event chooseNewEvent(String command);

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // Get the name of the button
        String command = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();

        displayNewEvent(chooseNewEvent(command));
    }
}
```

The only information I could find regarding this was:
https://github.com/wpilibsuite/shuffleboard/issues/358

Could someone point me in some direction to fix my bug?

Comment: Why are you marshaling an internal `com.sun` class to/from JSON? Stop that!!

Comment: What is that? How do I stop doing that?

Comment: What are you marshaling? It seems the only way this could happen is if you were trying to convert a JavaFX UI component of some kind to JSON. You should only be using JSON for *data*, not for any kind of UI component.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the added json file into an object.

Comment: What is your `Quest` class looks like, it must be having a `com.sun.javafx.jmx.HighlightRegion` field

Comment: I just added the class, but I'm really confused by this error because I don't use `com.sun.javafx.jmx.HighlightRegion` at all in my code.

Comment: Add more logs and also, try removing nodes from json and try to narrow down the problem. Your problem lies in `EventSequence`. Also, `Quest` has a list of `Quest`s, in this case, seems to add more confusion than solving a particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it was a Button array from `javafx.scene.control.Button` in my `Event` class that was causing the problem. I fixed it by making it `transient` so it would get ignored by GSON and not cause any problems.

Nevertheless, I have no idea why the Button array would cause this exception. Any thoughts?

Comment: If parent and subclass have field of same name